# Solve inhomogeneous Laplace Equation (Poisson's Equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation, linear-pde

First of all, it's not a homework or exams. I want to learn more about this PDE. So, if you don't mind please help me to solve this problem and i'll appreciate it.

Given problem=

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=x$

$x^2+y^2<3$

$u\left(\sqrt{3},\theta\right)=e^\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v=x^3/6$. Then
$$
     v_{xx}+v_{yy} = x.
$$
This reduces the problem to solving for $w=u-v$ satisfying
$$
              w_{xx}+w_{yy}=0 \\
              w(\sqrt{3},\theta)= e^{\theta}-r^3\cos^2(\theta)/6.
$$
And $u=w+v = w+x^3/6$ is your solution.